# Blacklisting Libraries/Dependencies within Java projects

Tags: java, sonarqube

From a high level point of view I am looking to create a centralised list of libraries/dependencies that are either out of date and should not be used or can be used under warning.

We are using SonarQube for code inspection/coverage and my preference would be to use work the "Blacklist" into here through rules/analysis. This would be the preferred option as it is indeed centralised and allows the selection of severity e.g a library totally blacklisted as opposed to a warning. Though I have seen this mentioned on forums I have not seen a practical example of doing it.

My question so is there a way of doing this and if so how? All other opinions are welcomed.

I have looked at mavens bannedDependencies feature but I don't like the fact that it would break a build, allow the developer to edit and is not centralised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Disallowed dependencies should not be used](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS3417) rule template is what you want. It will let you specify dependencies by group and artifact id pattern, with or without version numbers.

This rule is available from version 3.10 of the Java plugin.

Comment: Thank you! That looks perfect

Comment: Unfortunately our version of the plug in needs to be updated. Is there any example of how this would be implemented and where? I understand the logic just I want to understand the implementation.

Comment: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/c664c821388c50d718e73848d9ff59df95100c39/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks/xml/maven/DisallowedDependenciesCheck.java

Comment: Is there an example how to include this rule in sonarqube for a particular dependency ?